# checking multiple username and password in pycharm robotframework using for loop

Tags: python, pycharm, robotframework

I am trying to check multiple username and password for testing in robotframework using Pycharm. I am using Mac EI Captain.
Please help me out. I am trying to use the method given in Robot Framework Guide. Also, Is is possible or not? Or I have to use excel sheet or python file? Please let me knw. 
This is the piece of code I'm trying:

```
 *** Settings ***
Library  Selenium2Library
Resource  ../Resources/Common.robot
Resource  ../Resources/Yahoor.robot
Test Setup  Common.Begin Browser
#Test Teardown  Common.End Browser
Library  string

*** Variables ***
${BROWSER} =  firefox
${URL} =  https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?.src=fpctx&.intl=ca&.lang=en-CA&.done=https://ca.yahoo.com/
${PASS} =  ****

*** Test Cases ***
Yahoo Login Check Positive Testing
    [Tags]  Positive
    [Documentation]  Check for positive test
    @{STR}    Create List  user1  user2
    : FOR    ${Item}    IN    @{STR}

    Yahoor.Verify Display
    Yahoor.Input Email-id
    Yahoor.Check Pass Page
    Yahoor.Input Pass Credentials
```

Answer (score 0):

you can first call and retrieve all users in database and set them in a variable for example BODY and then get the username and passwords from the jsonbody     `:FOR    ${ELEMENT}    IN    @{BODY.json()}` and call your other keywords

Comment: I am new to this framework. I tried it but it didn't work for me. Is it possible to elaborate just using the selenium2library and not using python or javascript. I'm not familiar with the javascript.